# What is the Tomcat ROOT application and what are its advantages?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6

Basically the title. I am working on a legacy project that is under ROOT in `tomcathome/webapps`. What does this mean specifically for the webapp and tomcat when a file is deployed under this name, and why would somebody do that (i.e. what are the advantages)?

The project is using Java Servlets if that is important.

Is it simply that you can access the app via `mydomain.com:8080/` directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be accessed at `http://your-host.com/` rather than being accessed at `http://your-host.com/yourWebApp/`.

The advantage it that the URLs are shorter.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but is there any reason to do this other than aesthetics?

Comment: aesthetics, and user-friendlyness. When I go to google.com, I want to be able to type google.com in the address bar, and be at the google home page. I don't want to see Tomcat's default index page, and be forced to guess that the app is in fact at google.com/searchApp/